# Error when compiling Rcpp code in an R package using RStudio

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am using Rstudio to create a package, and exploring the use of the Rcpp package to gain access to C++ code, however, when trying to build the package, and error is being thrown as follows:

`fatal error: Rcpp.h: No such file or directory`

Inline C++ code compiles fine, its only when considering standalone C++ files in the `src` folder, obviously referring to the `#include <Rcpp.h>` directive at the head of the `.cpp` file.

I think it may have something to do with environment variables, does anyone know what the correct configuration is and how to fix for Rstudio operating in an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS environment?

The commands `sourceCpp('./src/xyz.cpp')` execute as to be expected, the error is being thrown when `Build and Reload` is executed from within the RStudio IDE.

Comment: have you considered posting this question on RStudio's forum? They are generally fast and responsive

Comment: Look, _many_ of us use Rcpp on Ubuntu, with or without RStudio and it just works.  Your question is rather vague though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is hard to say without having the package available. I guess you miss:

```
LinkingTo: Rcpp
```

in your DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: Thanks after adding that, and creating a few symlinks to Rcpp installation directories, problem fixed.

Comment: You should **not** need any symlinks, and doing so liberally will most likely create problems for your afterwards. Also:  try `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` and the resulting package and compare.

Answer (score 8):

Did you by chance start with *'Create a package'* in RStudio?  If so, are you aware that you may have missed its sibbling option *'Create a package w/ Rcpp'* ?

See the page on [**Using Rcpp with RStudio**](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/using_rcpp) site for details, and particularly the final section on package building.

Also note that we wrote an entire vignette [on using Rcpp with your own packages](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-package.pdf) so I suggest you have a look at that too.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for the above, it seems I am now getting another strange error when trying to use useDynLib(MYPACKAGE), reporting an undefined reference to `dgetrf_', any idea?

Comment: No, I have no idea as you *insist on not posting code*. Send a *reproducible* example to rcpp-devel, please.

Comment: Its not like that, I was just in the process of putting together a MWE, my package has ALOT of stuff in it, making it hard other than creating an effectively empty project. Anyway, turns out the culprit was the RcppArmadillo package, specifically, calling the determinant function for some reason, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same symptom (`Rcpp.h: No such file or directory`) when trying to install the "xml2" package on an Ubuntu 14 system.  In my case the root cause appeared to be a bad installation of package "Rcpp".  Some of the files were there (Rcpp/libs) but others were not (Rcpp/include).  I am not sure how the system got into this state but I suspect an installation of that package terminated part way through.  Re-installing package "Rcpp" cleared up the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your GCC has been updated, and it is different than the one you had when you installed R. I had the same problem.

I removed the package "Rccp" by using:

```
remove.packages("Rcpp")
```

Then you need to install it again. Just run:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Rcpp")
```