# Use CSV-Import in RStudio fails installing dependencies

Tags: r, rstudio, readr

I just updated to RStudio 1.0.136 and tried to import a csv. Therefore it wants me to install a package called `readr`. If I try this, it fails installing its dependency on `tibble` with error message:

```
RcppExports.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'Rcpp.h' file not found
#include <Rcpp.h>
         ^
```

Since this seems to be some problem with the package itself and the [integration of C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259299/error-when-compiling-rcpp-code-in-an-r-package-using-rstudio), is there anything I can do beside filing a bug report?

Comment: Why not try: `install.packages('readr', dependencies=TRUE)` ? Either that or separately install all of this list extracted from `packageDescription('readr')`  :::  `LinkingTo: Rcpp, BH
Imports: Rcpp (>= 0.11.5), curl, tibble, hms, R6
Suggests: testthat, knitr, rmarkdown, stringi, covr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognised that the error also occured for some other packages such as GGPLOT2. I updated my R version to 3.3 and all packages without success. Finally I ran `brew uninstall --force R` and `brew install R`, after that everything went fine. Now I have R version 3.4 installed (even that R reported before, that there was no newer version available).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to update all of your packages. Go to tools, then check for package updates, and update everything.  You should also check that you have the most current version of R installed. If neither of these solve your problem you might want to try reinstalling the Rccp package.

Comment: spellcheck needed ?